# How to create signed new PDF using already signed it on DOM page made by PHP

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, cakephp

I'm creating DOM page such as below by CakePHP3.

In PHP script

```
foreach($datas as $value){
  echo "td" . $value->record . "/td";
  echo "td" . $value->created . "/td";
  echo "td" . $value->username . "/td";
}
```

By user view

```
|record|created         |signature|
|------|----------------|---------|
|7.11  |17/5/15 11:22:33|user1    |
|9.22  |17/5/15 11:22:33|user2    |
```

And I've already made this page can output PDF using wkhtmltoPDF, FPDI on CakePDF.

Then, I made it can signature using TCPDF. But here the problem occurred.

This page can add record, and each record can sign by user certification file.
But created PDF don't carry over before signature information (i.e. signed time), every time only create each record new signature data.

For Example
created PDF on 17/5/15 21:41:33

```
|record|created         |signature|(ideal signed time)|(signed time on current system)|
|------|----------------|---------|-------------------|---------------------|
|7.11  |17/5/12 09:25:32|user1    |17/5/12 09:25:32   |17/5/15 21:41:33     |
|9.22  |17/5/15 21:41:33|user2    |17/5/15 21:41:33   |17/5/15 21:41:33     |
```

I studied FPDI how to additional data on existing PDF, but it only could find "To write down text into existing PDF, needs absolute coordinates where in it."

Surely, though using JavaScript can get absolute coordinates, it may have to do many things. For example, to write table border line, to adjust new records to  already existing table frame, and so on.

More than anything, to get absolute coordinates by JavaScript, need to open on browser before create PDF by user. (I only know to way to get absolute coordinates of HTML tag by using JavaScript, '`window.getBoundingClientRect();`')

Indeed, I would have no choice but to use JavaScript and to draw text and frame by using absolute coordinates.
But I want to append data more simply. For example, "By using older PDF, This tag section adding it!"

I thought other way. it prepare blank but user signed PDF. Next, on creating PDF DOM records, create PDF of DOM view using prepared PDF. Then could create signed PDF. (But it is too apparently. I don't want do it.)

Anyone have good ideas?
Or rather, how everyone create PDF on carry over PDF information?
Please teach me it.

Comment: Could you be more specific on your main question?

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version (last line in vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt or lib/Cake/VERSION.txt)

Comment: >Rayann Nayran ok, I want hear the most is "how can I build new information while keeping old information on PDF, especially signature"

Comment: CakePHP version is 3.3.16

Comment: So Do you want edit a pdf file?

Comment: yes. I want to write additionally rather than edit. (It seems for me that "Edit" means can delete already existed string in PDF. In my assumption, If new string to write is overlapped already existed string, then created PDF must be lapped over both string as if line-through. It cannot delete already existed string.)